# Treated for Anxiety During Pandemic - can I get 3rd Class Medical

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

I started doing my dual instruction recently, as I am pursuing a Private Pilots License.  I have begun researching the medical that will be required, and had a couple question I was hoping to get opinions on before moving forward.

I'm a bit of a hypochondiriac, and during the Covid-19 pandemic, I began to experience some severe anxiety surrounding my health.  I went to the doctor, and he said I have generalized anxiety disorder and panic disorder, because I experienced a few panic attacks while laying in bed. I began treatment with Prozac, and ceased taking it approximately 4 months ago (9-10 months total).  I am back to normal now, but if I login to my account with my doctor, it still has Generalized Anxiety Disorder and Major Depressive Disorder listed. Concurrent to these diagnoses, I obtained my college degree and handled high stress situations as a D1 athlete, so it obviously isn't affecting me in any way that would be detrimental to aviation. Will this cause any problems for me, and if so, is there anything I should do before mentioning it to my flight instructor and getting my medical to ensure it goes as smoothly as possible, such as going back to my primary doctor and asking to be classified as cured? I have already sunk substantial time and money into this endeavor, and would be crushed if a technicality such as this would hold me back.

(I read similar threads on this forum, but felt none addressed my specific circumstances, so I am creating a new thread)

Thanks, Gary

Comment: Please add what jurisdiction you are asking about. The general advice on here though, is to go to an AME as a **consultation** before applying for a medical.

Comment: I am in the United States.  Thank you for your reply.  I appreciate the advice and will look into the consultation as you mentioned.

Comment: What @TomMcW said is excellent advice. Talk to an AME first, make sure you make it clear you are not applying for a medical, you just want an opinion.